# Get document id from Firestore after fetching document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the document id of a firestore document after successfully fetching the document. I am fetching user data from firestore collections like this

```
const ref = await db.collection('users').where('phone', '==', phone)
            .where('password', '==', password).get();
```

I have a valid document after executing this query.

```
const data = ref.docs[0].data();
```

How can I get the auto generated document id? I tried `data.id` and `data.path`, it is returning undefined.

How can I access the auto generated id?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my code, it was actually trying to get the data id, instead of document id 
i got the document id by adding `const docRefId = ref.docs[0].id;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Sony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469536/get-document-id-from-firestore-after-fetching-document/49469746#49469746), you can get the **document reference** as well:

```js
const docRefId = ref.docs[0].ref;
```