# OrderBy and StartAt with two different fields firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

In my app, I have comments that have a field value of threadCommentCount. I want to order the comments using orderBy threadCommentCount descending and then have pagination continue this using startAfter(lastThreadCommentCount). The problem is when threadCommentCount is 0, which is a lot of them, it will return and the same data every time since it starts at 0 everytime. Here is the query:

```
popularCommentsQuery = db
                        .collection('comments')
                        .where('postId', '==', postId)
                        .orderBy('threadCommentCount', 'desc')
                        .startAfter(startAfter)
                        .limit(15)
                        .get()
```

This will return the same comments everytime once threadComment count is 0. I'm unable to send the last document snapshot because im using cloud functions and I dont want to send the documentSnapshot in a get query parameter. I don;t really care how the comments are ordered after threadCommentCount is 0, I just need to not get any duplicates. Any help is great!

Answer (score 2):

All Firestore queries have an [implicit](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2854#issuecomment-552986650) `orderBy("__name__", direction)` to resolve any ties between documents that have the same values for the other named `orderBy` fields.  This makes the final sort order stable.  But it also enables you to pass another argument to `startAfter` to provide the document ID of the anchor document that you wish to use for the purpose of pagination.

```
.startAfter(lastThreadCommentCount, lastDocumentId)
```

Between these two values, you should be able to uniquely identify the document in the result set to start the next page.

Comment: Too many cursor values specified. The specified values must match the orderBy() constraints of the query. Do i have to add another orderBy, if so where? I want to order it by threadComment count then by commentId if the threadCommentCount is the same.

Comment: Sure, try to explicitly add the orderBy on \_\_name\_\_ after the first one.

Comment: So it will look like this? popularCommentsQuery = db
                            .collection('comments')
                            .where('postId', '==', postId)
                            .orderBy('threadCommentCount', 'desc')
                            .orderBy('commentId', 'desc')
                            .startAfter(startAfter, lastCommentId)
                            .limit(15) or do i literally add "__ name __" in the second orderBy field?

Comment: Nvm, an idea popped up in my head that i can just pass the commentId to the backend and get the snapshot from there to pass into startAfter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

so, I was trying OrderBy and StartAfter with two different fields(time,key) in firestore to establish pagination in flastList.

**Key point is that we can pass document snapshot to define the query cursor [[reference]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor)**

Here is how I managed to do it.

step 1: get the document Id(which is auto generated by firebase) with where() [[reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49469746/11139453)

```
const docRef = firestore().collection('shots').where('key','==','custom_key')
const fbDocIdGeneratedByFirebase= await docRef.get().docs[0].id;
```

step 2: get document snapshot with firebase generated document Id (which we got in the 1st step)

```
const docRef2= firestore().collection('shots').doc(fbDocIdGeneratedByFirebase)
const snapshot = await docRef2.get();
```

**step 3**: pass the **snapshot** got in step 2 to **startAfter()** so that the cursor will point there [[reference]](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor)

```
 let additionalQuery =  firestore().collection('shots')
         .orderBy("time", "desc")
         .startAfter(snapshot)
         .limit(this.state.limit)      
 let documentSnapshots = await additionalQuery.get(); // you know what to do next
...
```

**Can you Improve the solution??**